# Speaker sound plays for a few seconds then static sound and stops

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-one

I am using my oneplus one phone - I originally bought it on cyanogenmod 11 but instantly upgraded to cyanogenmod 12
I notices that the issues was happening (the issue is specifically that when playing any app sounds - literally any thing apart from touch sounds - then the sound plays out of the speakers for a few seconds then makes a staticy sound and clicks then goes off. After this even touch sounds turn off - eventually they come back on, after locking the screen or rebooting - but as soon as you play any other sound the bug happens again) and when I noticed it was happening I tried turning off profiles, changing interruption settings so it never happens, adjusting volume levels, clearing app cache, system restore then flashed a new ROM onto it (oxygenOS) and that worked for a little bit but now the bug is back and I have tried all the other fixes I tried before - even booting to TWRP recovery and wiping cache and dalvik.
I have rooted my phone so I could get TWRP.

Can anyone help? Any suggestions? Anyone experienced anything similar?

EDIT: it could be volume related - it seems to be alright as long as the volume is under just over half way, kind of, my alarm increases volume gradually (reaching max in 15 seconds) and I changed it so it reached max in 30 seconds and the sound lasted longer before glitching and cutting out. As well as opening a youtube video at low media volume and gradually increasing volume until it got high enough to glitch out again.

Any suggestions are welcome as I'm not absolutely sure it's anything to do with volume.

I am relatively sure it's software as it does work now and again (but then goes again!)